# Compare two arrays and validate if master array has child array values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have two arrays.I want to verify if the data in one array exists in another array.
MasterArray

```
[
    {
        "productDisplay": "ZXP 105",
        "productNumber": "WZDR 112"
    },
    {
        "productDisplay": "ZXP 106",
        "productNumber": "WZDR 113"
    }
]
```

ChildArray

```
[{productDisplay:"ZXP 105",
productNumber:"WZDR 112"}]
```

Code I am verifiying

```
expect(MasterArray).to.deep.include(ChildArray)
```

> expect(MasterArray).to.deep.include(ChildArray)
>    UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError: expected [ Array(2) ] to deep include [ { productDisplay: 'ZXP 105',
>       productNumber: 'WZDR 112'})]

How to execute testcase for this scenario?

Comment: I assume you're working with unit tests. Checking out your code I realized you have different key names. The parent has _snakeCase_ keys and the child has _CamelCase_. Probably you are having a case sensitive issue when comparing using `deep.include`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arrayA = [5,6,8];
let arrayB = [5,6,8];

let sameArrays = (arrayA.length == arrayB.length) && arrayA.every(function(element, index) {
    return element === arrayB[index]; 
});

document.write('Both are arrays are the same: ' + sameArrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var master = [{
        "productDisplay": "ZXP 105",
        "productNumber": "WZDR 112"
    },
    {
        "productDisplay": "ZXP 106",
        "productNumber": "WZDR 113"
    }
];
var child = [{ProductDisplay:"ZXP 105",
ProductNumber:"WZDR 112"}];

var res = master.includes((product,index) => product.productNumber == child[index].ProductNumber);
console.log(res);
```